# Why does my liquid toothpaste's Kosher for Pesach sign have an expiration date?‎

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I have an Israeli brand of liquid tooth paste from a company called Tayadent,‎ which says on it כשר לפסח תש"פ -‎ why would it matter what year it is for the hecsher?‎

Thanks

Comment: next year they may change their manufacturing process, change their ingredients, and/or lose their hechsher. In that case, you'll still be able to use the toothpaste you bought in 5780, because it was certified kosher for passover

Comment: @Menachem Isn't that true of any product with any hechsher? If it's no longer kosher, don't put a symbol on it